# Finding subsets of the set of first $n$ natural numbers such that the average of the elements of subset also belong to the parent set.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, induction, recursion

Let $S$$=${$1,2,...,n$}.
Let $T$ be a non-empty subset of $S$. We call $T$ to be *good* if the average of the elements of $T$ belongs to $S$.
For example, let $n$$=$$10$.
Then, {$1,2,3$} is a good subset, but {$1,2,4$} is not.
We denote the number of good subsets of $S$ by $f(n)$. Show that $f(n)+n$ is even.

We were given this problem in our problem seminar . I tried to solve this by establishing some sort of recursion between $f(n+1)$ and $f(n)$ and then applying induction on $n$. But I failed. Please help me ,someone . I would be very thankful .

Comment: This can't be true.  $f(3) = 4$ but $4+3$ is not even.

Comment: And if you mean only *proper* subsets then $f(1) = 0$.

Comment: You might consider that if $\{a_1,a_2,...a_k\}$ is good then $\{(n-a_1),(n-a_2)....,(n-a_k)\}$ is good.  And if $T$ is good then $T-\{average(T)\}$ has the same average and is therefore not good.  And all the good subsets of $\{1,...n\}$ will be good subsets of $\{1,...,n+1\}$ that the only new good subsets must contain $n$.  But I'm not sure what you are trying to show.  $f(3)+3=7$ is odd $f(4)+4=10$ is even...

Comment: Or is $0$ a natural number so that $S_n=$ the first $n$ natural numbers $= \{0,1,2,....,n-1\}$? $S_3= \{0,1,2\}$ is *not* good and $f(3)=3$ and $f(4) = f(3)+|\{\{3\},\{1,2,3\}\}|=5$ and... no, still doesn't work.....

Comment: @fleablood Taking $f(3)$ , we see the parent set is {$1,2,3$} giving the required subsets as {$1,3$} , {$1,2,3$} , and the $3$ singleton sets {$1$},{$2$},{$3$}. Which gives us a total of $5$. Now $5+3=8$, even.

Comment: @Shubhayan18  Did you perhaps mean to say, in defining good, "the average  of the elements of $T$ belongs to $S$"?  Otherwise why do you count {1,3} when determining $f(3)$.

Comment: The average of $1,3$ is $2$ and $2\not \in \{1,3\}$ so $\{1,3\}$ is not a good set.

Comment: If you mean the average is an element of *S* rather than of T, then that's just a set whose average is an integer.  Also the only good subsets of $S_n$ that are not good subsets of $S_n$ are sets with element $n$.  So the good subset of those are the singleton $\{n\}$ and sets $\{a_1,...a_m, n\}$ if $avr(a_1,...a_m)=A$ then $\frac {mA + n}{m+1}$ is an integer.

Comment: I  am really sorry for the mistake. Please do not mind , gentlemen.

Comment: Well.  Tell us what the actual definition of "good" is and what your question is and we will help you.  It seems like a fun and intriguing question but I don't actually know which definition of "good" should be or what statement we should be proving.